# (Android) How to retrieve current location using Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, location, google-play-services

I'm fairly new to Android app development and I'm currently looking into retrieving the user's current location (coordinates & city) using **Google Play Services**. As of now, I fail to find any clear step-by-step tutorial on doing so.
Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use fused location provider try to search it on Google you will find many examples

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html) APIs in the Google Play Service library to retrieve the device's [last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html):

```
 Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (lastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = lastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = lastLocation.getLongitude();

//Once you get the coordinates, you can retrieve the city name using the Geocoder class:

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                    String cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

            }

         }
```

In your manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here's [a detailed tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) to help you

Answer (score 1):

## Current Location = Last location

This is what Google Android documentation says about getting current location using **FusedLocationProvider**

> In most cases, you are interested in the user's current location,
> which is usually equivalent to the last known location of the device.

## How to do this?

**You can use this method**

```
public void getCurrentLocation() {

      FusedLocationProviderClient locationProviderClient = LocationServices.
                                           getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);


     locationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {

                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                     Log.d("Location",currentLocation.toString());
                 
                  }
             });

      }

}
```

You need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
The above code is the simplified version. If your app runs on the Android Lollipop and above then you need to ask for [Location permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) **ALSO**.

You can see the full code [HERE](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/blob/master/GooglePlayServicesLocationAPIDemo/app/src/main/java/rohksin/com/googleplayserviceslocationapidemo/MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to connect GoogleApiClient in latest google play services, you can directly request location updates.

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(20 * 1000);
mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

            }
        };
```